# How to serialize enum with converter inside another custom converter

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a custom JSON converter, because 3rd party API accept specific structure only.

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) 
{
   var bodyRequest = (IRequest) value;
   writer.WriteStartObject();
   writer.WritePropertyName(bodyRequest.RequestName);
   writer.WriteStartObject();
   writer.WritePropertyName("-xmlns");
   writer.WriteValue("http://example.com");
   writer.WritePropertyName(bodyRequest.WrapperName);
   writer.WriteStartObject();

   var contractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver {
    IgnoreSerializableAttribute = false
   };
   var properties = value.GetType().GetProperties();

   foreach(var propertyInfo in properties) {
    if (HasAttribute(propertyInfo, typeof(JsonIgnoreAttribute))) {
     continue;
    }
    var propValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(value);    
    var propertyName = contractResolver.GetResolvedPropertyName(propertyInfo.Name);
    writer.WritePropertyName(propertyName);
    writer.WriteValue(propValue);

   }
   writer.WriteEndObject();
   writer.WriteEndObject();
   writer.WriteEndObject();
}
```

So, I create strcuture with help of `WriteXXX` methods, then I get all properties and serialize them. All works fine, but I need to handle Enums. For example, we have the following request model:

```
public class ExampleRequest : IRequest
{
   public long Id{ get; set; }

   [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
   public CarType CarType { get; set; }

   public string RequestName => "Request";
   public string WrapperName => "SendData";
}

public enum CarType
{
   [EnumMember(Value = "NEW_CAR")
   New,
   [EnumMember(Value = "OLD_CAR")
   Old
}
```

Currently, after serialization I see that `CarType` has numeric value 0 or 1,I understand that I use reflection and `StringEnumConverter` is ignored. How to properly serialize in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your loop, check whether the property has a `JsonConverterAttribute` applied.  If so, get the type of converter, instantiate it and then call its `WriteJson` method instead of writing the value directly.  Otherwise, just write the value as you are doing now.

In other words, replace this line:

```
writer.WriteValue(propValue);
```

with this:

```
var att = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<JsonConverterAttribute>();
if (att != null)
{
    var converter = (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(att.ConverterType);
    converter.WriteJson(writer, propValue, serializer);
}
else
{
    writer.WriteValue(propValue);
}
```